# Firestore query subcollection of specific snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Pretty simple, I'd like to query the subcollection of a snapshot and return it to my front-end.

**Here's the example.**

```
const docUser = await db.collection('users').where("slug", "==", req.body.slug).limit(1).get();
if (docUser.empty) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Could not find user.' });

const collectionProjects = docUser.docs[0].collection('projects'); // Err.
return res.status(200).send({ projects: collectionProjects.data() });
```

**Here's the error I get.**

> TypeError: docUser.docs[0].collection is not a function

How should I return my `projects`?

Comment: What are you expecting this to return?  If you're trying to make a second query against another collection, you will need to write that code using another `get()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docUser` is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). By doing `docUser.docs[0]` you get a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot). You need to use the [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#ref) property of this `QueryDocumentSnapshot` in order to get a `DocumentReference` on which you can call the [`collection()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection) method.

Then use again the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method, as follows:

```
const docUser = await db.collection('users').where("slug", "==", req.body.slug).limit(1).get();
if (docUser.empty) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Could not find user.' });

const collectionProjects = await docUser.docs[0].ref.collection('projects').get();
//See above the addition of ref
```

Then do whatever you want with `collectionProjects`, which is `QuerySnapshot`. But note that you cannot do `collectionProjects.data()`, since there isn't any `data()` method for a `QuerySnapshot`. You should probably use [`forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach) or, again, `docs`.